# How to prove that $f(x,y)=3+2x+y$ is continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

The question is to prove that the function $f(x,y,z) = 3+2x+y$ is continuous everywhere.
My approach uses the delta-epsilon method. $|(x,y)-(a,b)|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|$.

---

All I did was trying to follow the method, but when I got $$|3+2x-y-3-2a+b|=|(2x-2a)-(y-b)|$$
I dont know what to do after this.

Comment: What is the domain of the function?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial and reference on MathJax.

Comment: The domain of the function is all real number

Comment: @Frostsk That's very unlikely.

Comment: @GitGud In the question it just said prove it is continuous without any other information.

Comment: @Frostsk In your question you write both $f(x,y,z)$ and $f(x,y)$, this is highly incompatible.

Comment: @GitGud because I thought there is no z in the function so I can just focus on x y direction.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|=\\=|2(x-a)+y-b|\leq \\ \leq 2|x-a|+|y-b|\leq \\ \leq 2(|x-a|+|y-b|)\leq \\ \leq 4\sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}=4|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\epsilon$

if

$|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Use
$|u+v|^2
\le 2(u^2+v^2)
$
with
$u = x-a$
and
$v = y-b$.